# Is "Total Paid" in a report really supposed to show Amount Paid plus fees?

Tags: civireport

I am for the first time retrieving payment data for event participants through CiviReports. One of my columns is Total Paid, but for those who registered and paid online, this column shows numbers like "$409.10", which is the amount they paid $400 plus the $9.10. The Net Amount correctly shows $390.90.

I'm thinking this is a bug, but maybe there is another field I should use?

[edited to add:]
I'm very sure this is a bug at this point, and I'll add it to the issues board. I'm running 4.6.8 and I can replicate it on the demo site:
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/39?reset=1

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it could be a bug. Can you please [edit](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/posts/6240/edit) your question to include what version of CiviCRM you are using and what report you are running.

Are you able to duplicate this result on the [master demo site](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/)?